# What does the ${\uparrow}{\uparrow}$ symbol mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question asked is

> calculate the value of: $\dfrac{2\mathbin{{\uparrow}{\uparrow}}3}{2^{100}}$

and I have no idea what the ${\uparrow}{\uparrow}$ symbol means.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation.

Answer (score 2):

[Tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). See [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation).